# RSpec not retrieving the array associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am using RSpec for testing, and I am new to TDD, I've searched extensively for a solution but I can't find anything that really fits the problem I have. I am using FactoryGirl to create my objects. I have written tests that pass on the belongs_to has_many associations.  But the last test fails, the array of expenses is always empty even though the tests above it pass for the presence of the expenses.

```
describe "expenses associations" do
  before { @job.save }
  let(:expense_one) { FactoryGirl.create(:expense, job: @job) }
  let(:expense_two) { FactoryGirl.create(:expense, job: @job) }

  it "should have expenses" do
    # This test passes
    expect(@job.expenses.find_by(id: expense_one.id).expenseamount).to eq expense_one.expenseamount
    expect(expense_one.expenseamount).to eq 12.34
  end
  it "should destroy associated expenses" do
    expenses = @job.expenses(true).to_a

    #This expectation passes
    expect(expense_one.job_id).to eq @job.id

    #This expectation will fail
    expect(expenses).not_to be_empty
  end
```

And here are the models

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :expenses, dependent: :destroy
  validates :jobname, presence: true
  validates :jobamount, format: { with: /\A\d{1,6}(\.\d{0,2})?\z/ }, 
                      numericality: [greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 999999]
  validates :paidamount, format: { with: /\A\d{1,6}(\.\d{0,2})?\z/ }, 
                      numericality: [greater_than_or_equal_to: 0]
  validate :not_in_the_future
  validate :paid_less_than_billed

  class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :expenseamount,   format: { with: /\A\d{1,5}(\.\d{0,2})?\z/ }, 
                      numericality: [greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 99999]
  validates :expensename, presence: true
  validates :job_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :job
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the usage of `let`. lets are lazy constructs. that means that they only get evaluated when called.

in your case this means

```
expenses = @job.expenses(true).to_a # let not evaluated
expect(expense_one.job_id).to eq @job.id # let evaluated
expect(expenses).to be_empty
# now it should work
expenses = @job.reload.expenses(true).to_a
expect(expenses).to_not be_empty
```

Comment: Okay, I added reload, but it only works with `expenses = @job.reload.expenses`, which is okay except the array I'm wanting to test, expenses, is empty after `@job.destroy`.  I can't find anyway to create a copy of @job.expenses

Comment: running `@job.expenses.to_a` should create a copy of all the objects in the relation. keep in mind that calling `.expenses` does not fetch the stuff from the db yet. it just returns a proxy object that allows you to chain stuff like `@job.expenses.where(xxx)`. in any case, after you destroyed the job, why should there be any expenses left?

Comment: `@job.expenses.to_a` is returning an empty array, after I destroy the job I want to test to be sure that the expenses were destroyed too.  It works when I manually add expenses and then destroy the job, but it'd be nice to have it in a test.

Comment: that's where you would use a `expect {...}.to change(Job, :count).by(-1)`

Comment: So what I've done is I tried as many variants of `@job.expenses.count` as I could think of to just get a count of the number of expenses prior to vaporizing, because I'm not trying to test the destruction of the job, but that the expenses associated are cleared out as well.  I never get 2, I always get 0.